# PowerShell, Difference between Start-Job and a hidden Start-Process that calls powershell.exe

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, background-process, start-process, start-job

I can use `Start-Job` to run a process in the background for asynchronous / parallel jobs.

However, I could also use something like the following with `Start-Process`  which gives me other options for an asynchronous background process.

```
$command = "choco install openoffice -y"
Start-Process "powershell.exe" -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "-sta -noprofile -executionpolicy unrestricted $command"
```

What are the pros and cons to using each method?

Comment: You can't (easily) redirect output of a command using `Start-Process` to display it in the console or process it further. What are your requirements to consider `Start-Process`?

Comment: Mostly, I just want to run background processes as quickly as possible. I've been using the above `Start-Process` option for a while, but wondered if there are downsides to this approach. Would one be faster than the other? Are there other considerations? As you say, we have the ability to interact with `Start-Job` a bit via `Get-Job` etc, but I'm curious if there are other factors that might make one method a better option than the other.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I would expect both to be similar, performance-wise. `Start-Job` creates a process as well. `Start-Job` gives you more options for passing input into the process, e. g. using the `using:variable` construct. Input and output can be objects, not just strings as in the `Start-Process` case. So `Start-Job` is better integrated into PowerShell, whereas `Start-Process` is more low-level.